# No Suitable Video Mode Detected

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 from a DVD to a VersaLogic VL-EPM-31EAP which uses a single core Atom E3815 and integrated Intel Gen 7 graphics. When I boot from the CD, BIOS executes as expected followed by the following error messages:

error: no suitable video mode detected.
error: no video mode activated.
Booting in blind mode.

However the boot process continues and Ubuntu starts and installs normally. With 16.04 installed the same errors appear every time the boot process transfers from Bios to the boot loader (an assumption on my part). I did find some solutions that involved modifying grub.cfg but did not work. Actually enabling GRUB_TERMINAL="console" created another boot error: "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules." Disabling it did not remove the error so now I have two problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you could try to add the following to your grub script

```
insmod all_video
```

(or invoke from the grub prompt)...

Although to TBH that didn't work for me.

I'm trying to figure out grub2 myself...I'll let you know if I figure this one out.